# How to get attacker mac address aireplay-ng

Tags: ids, mac-address, aircrack-ng, deauth-attack

I'm currently working on a WIPS and I would like to know how to obtain the attacking MAC address when he launches a aireplay-ng deauth attack.

On wireshark, if the attacker broadcast the deauth attack it appears as source address my router and destination address broadcast. If the attacker launches the attack to a specific victim it appears as source address my router and destination the victims MAC address.

Is there any way to obtain the attacker MAC?

Comment: You mean, even if the attacker spoofs the MAC? You want the real MAC?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @schroeder I think that's impossible, but I'm not sure. I mean, I'm using aireplay-ng to start an deauth attack, I'm not spoofing any MAC, I mean, I'm not using macchanger or any similar tool. I would like to obtain the MAC address used by the attacker to launch the attack.

Comment: What command are you using to launch the deauth? I think you need to review how deauth works.

Comment: I'm using aireplay-ng -0 1 -a AP-bsid monitor-mode-interface

Comment: Ok, now how does your machine convince the other machines that you are the AP? You send out deauth packets, but why do the other machines listen to you?

Comment: My machine spoof the address, it makes sense. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I think the frames count is rising of the attackers mac address with every deauth, so you could display it with airodump-ng in a "live" session. But this is not that you can log it as far as I know.

Comment: Ok, but what if the attacker falsifies the frame count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deauth attacks require that the attacker spoofs the MAC address. What you are asking is to somehow get the MAC address of the attacker even if it is spoofed.

This is not possible from packet captures.

There is a *potential* that if the attacker hangs around long enough and sends packets from the real MAC on the network, then you *might* be able to correlate that traffic to the deauth traffic and conclude that the MAC is the attacker's. But there are a lot of things that would have to occur for that to be possible.